# why jvisualvm jdk1.8.0_92 profiling doesnt work with tomcat 8 on windows 7?

Tags: profiling, jvisualvm

i use jdk1.8.0_92  and want to profile my app deployed on tomcat 8 but it doesnt work ,i'm using  windows 7

Profiler error (Fri May 06 18:47:43 EET 2016): exception while trying to connect to the target JVM:
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

Comment: Please include your exact actions that lead up to the error.

Comment: i started the jvisualvm and double click on tomcat icon , then went to profile tab , clicked on cpu , message about calibration had came out , then message saying  "connecting to target vm" , but this message was took along time , when i opened the log file  from about menu , i found out :Profiler error (Fri May 06 18:47:43 EET 2016): exception while trying to connect to the target JVM: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in profiler. Try to run jvisualvm from command line like this:

```
bin\jvisualvm.exe -J-Dorg.netbeans.profiler.separateConsole=true
```

Source: [here](https://markmail.org/message/g2gefpmxfnk42cgu)